# An injective derivative function on a open ball

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, derivatives

$\textbf{MY PROBLEM:}$ Let $f: U\rightarrow R^n$ be $C^1$ in the open set $U\subset R^m$. If $f'(a) $ is 1-1 for $a\in U$ then there exist a open ball *B* such that $f'(x) $ is 1-1 for each $x\in B$.

$\textbf{MY ATTEMPT:}$ I considere jacobian matrix $Jf(a) $. This matrix must have $m$ vevtors LI. I want to use the continuity for prove the result, but I don't know how I can use it correctly.

Comment: Think of determinants; that's probably simpler. Also, if a continuous function is non-zero at a point, what can you say about it in a sufficiently small neighborhood?

Comment: You have reason, I though of determinants and I got a prove. I had forgotten determinants absolutely. Thanks a lot!